# Read in a text file and upload it to excel using Java

Tags: java, excel

I am reading in a text file, and then performing some validations on the file after which I am trying to put that file into an excel file. But I am able to add only the last row into the excel document and not every row. Any help is appreciated. Thank You.
Here is what I have so far:

```
LinkedList<String[]> llist = new LinkedList<>();

String[] data;

File temp = new File("file.txt");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
for (int i = 0; i < llist.size(); i++) {
    if(i==0){
        bw.newLine();
    }
    else{
        data = llist.get(i);

    String empid1 = data[0];
    String fname = data[1];
    String ccode1 = data[2];

    if(data[2].equals("IND")) {
        replace = data[2].replaceAll("IND", "IN");
        ccode1 = replace;
    }
    else if(data[2].equals("USA")) {
        replace = data[2].replaceAll("USA", "US");
        ccode1 = replace;
    }

    else {
        ccode1 = data[2];
    }

    String newData=empid1+","+fname+","+ccode1;

    XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    FileOutputStream outstream=new FileOutputStream("data.xls");
    XSSFSheet spreadSheet = workBook.createSheet("Clean");
    int row_num = 0;
    for(String[] str : llist) {
        XSSFRow row = spreadSheet.createRow(row_num++);
        int cell_num = 0;
        for(String value : str) {
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cell_num++);
            cell.setCellValue(value);
        }
    }

    workBook.write(outstream);
}
}

bw.close();

}

}
```

Comment: looks like you are re-writing the excel document for each line of the original file...Isn't the second loop inside the first one?

Comment: Yes, second loop is inside the first loop, and I am writing the data into the excel file with any validation changes that happens in the data.

Comment: In that way it looks like you are trying to do read, validate and write all at the same time. I suggest you structure your code better (take the second loop out) and it'll be easier to identify the bug that way.

Comment: With this code, I am able to get all the data, but this data has not gone through data validation rules, and that is the problem that I am facing. I tried to enter in the newData into my column, but it is entering everything into one cell, instead of separate cells.

Comment: Yes, you are writing to excel document directly from `llist` variable. You are not using your validated data.

Comment: I need help with that only. I am not sure how to enter the validated data into the excel file as I have tried to do that but have not been able to do it correctly

Comment: So once I have updated the columns with the correct data, I can add the updated columns to the `llist` and then just loop through it, and it will work?

Comment: We'll see if it works. Also I'd move the Excel document creation outside the main loop too. You just need to create the document once right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180386/discussion-between-agugglez-and-user2529660).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your code like this:

```
LinkedList < String[] > llist = new LinkedList < > ();

String[] data;

File temp = new File("file.txt");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));

XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream("data.xls");
XSSFSheet spreadSheet = workBook.createSheet("Clean");

for (int i = 0; i < llist.size(); i++) {
 if (i == 0) {
  bw.newLine();
 } else {
  data = llist.get(i);

  String empid1 = data[0];
  String fname = data[1];
  String ccode1 = data[2];

  if (data[2].equals("IND")) {
   replace = data[2].replaceAll("IND", "IN");
   ccode1 = replace;
  } else if (data[2].equals("USA")) {
   replace = data[2].replaceAll("USA", "US");
   ccode1 = replace;
  } else {
   ccode1 = data[2];
  }

  //String newData=empid1+","+fname+","+ccode1;

  XSSFRow row = spreadSheet.createRow(i);

  XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue(empid1);

  cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(fname);

  cell = row.createCell(2);
  cell.setCellValue(ccode1);
 }
}

workBook.write(outstream);
bw.close();
```

Comment: But if I did not know the number of rows in my file, then how do I implement that?

Comment: You keep the loop through `llist`, just not the one through `str`.

Comment: Can you show that as well in your answer? Also, `llist` does not contain the validated data.

Comment: Just did. It doesn't really matter that `llist` contains validated data as long as it has the same number of rows.

Comment: Just one more question, is there a way to loop through newData, instead of writing   to set each cell value?

Comment: Not really since `newData` is of type `String`. I'm not 100% sure but if you iterate through a `String` you'll probably loop through each character.

Comment: I ran the code and it is just including the last row and not every row, and each row in the excel file has the last row's data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180387/discussion-between-agugglez-and-user2529660).